# Python virtualenv: Unable to install Python 3.5

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have created a `virtualenv` using `pip` but unable to install `python 3.5` in the virtual environment. When I try this:

`virtualenv venv1 --python=python3.5`

I am getting this error:

`The path python3.5 (from --python=python3.5) does not exist`

But I am able to install `python 2.7` in the virtual environment without any issues. The error message is not clear, please suggest how to install `python 3.5` in this virtual environment.

Comment: Try with full path: `--python=/usr/bin/python3.5` for example.

Comment: You dont need to add ```--python=python3.5``` while creating virtual environment

Comment: You need to have Python3.5 installed to create an environment with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Python 3 by downloading it from official Python Website https://python.org . You can then call 'virtualenv --name' from your command line and this will create a virtual environment at the current directory with the --name you provided. It will also install Python 3 for you. Simple